# LinkedIn Access_token request getting error using jsoauth library

Tags: javascript, xcode, cordova, linkedin-api

hi i am try to integrate LinkedIn with my mobile application which is developing in phonegap with Xcode.
Now i have get the authorization using javascript library from github(https://github.com/bytespider/jsOAuth/blob/daa8823a02fa570b285ac26f66ff6c5d8be9d4ec/src/OAuth/Consumer.js) 
jsoauth but i do not know how to set header for "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken" any one please give example for it.Now i got oauth_token,verifier,oath_token_secret.how can i use it? i get the problem send like

code is:

var options={

```
    consumerKey:'XXXXXXXXXX',

    consumerSecret:'XXXXXXXX',

    verifier: verifier,    

    signatureMethod:'HMAC-SHA1'

   };

    oauth = OAuth(options);

    oauth.post('https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken', null,

               function(data) {alert('acess');   

               window.plugins.childBrowser.close(); 

               },
              function(data) {
              alert('no access');
              console.log(data.error);

               }

              );
```

here the error function called and Xcode error shows like:

*** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate:  *** -[JKArray objectAtIndex:]: index (1) beyond bounds (1)

any one help me how get the AccessToken of LinkeIn.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can set the verifier as an option.

Try using the function

```
oauth.setVerifier('verifier')
```

&

```
oauth.setAccessToken('MY-ACCESS-KEY', 'MY-ACCESS-SECRET');
```

http://bytespider.github.io/jsOAuth/api-reference/

After that, the jsOAuth will set the headers for you.

I also just had a problem fetching the access token using this library and it turned out that it was including the callback parameter unnecessarily, which made the request fail.